# Migrate GApps OAuth 1.0 to OAuth 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, calendar, google-apps-marketplace

I am developing an application in ASP.NET which is having OAUth 1.0 implemented for Google Apps user and it is totally outdated implementation. Now I need to convert this to new implementation i.e. OAuth 2.0. My use for integrating Google Apps is to integrate Google calendar service in my application. Can any one please help me in this regard that what are key points that I need to take care for future perspective or how can I start into this. Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use Google Calendar API V3 in order to use OAuth 2

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/

There is a good summary of the migration from v2 to v3 here

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/migration

Details on Authentication are here

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/auth

We used to use v2 and 2LO for authentication we now use Service Accounts which provide for full access to the users in the Domain.  Here is a snippet showing the auth process

```
        X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "certs//" + certificateFile, certificatePassword, X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

        ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
        new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
        {
            Scopes = new[] { Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.CalendarService.Scope.Calendar },
            User = user
        }.FromCertificate(certificate));

        Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.CalendarService service = new Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = "AppX",
        });

            Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.Data.Event evv = service.Events.Get(user, "6ebr4dp452m453n468movuntag").Execute();
            EventsResource.UpdateRequest ur = new EventsResource.UpdateRequest(service, evv, user, evv.Id);
            ur.Execute();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. May I know What are the changes that I need to do on my market place app. Because till now we have only ConsumerKey and ConsumerSecreat, but in Version 3 we need to specify serviceAccountEmail and certificates, so do we need to create separate App for having serviceAccountEmail & certificates.

Comment: ConsumerKey and Secret are gone.  You'll need to create a new listing with the new marketplace.  The old listing will be no use.  There is a migration API for bringing across users.  You will generate certificates etc in the API panel.  Look through the documentation at https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/preparing

Comment: Thanks now I got it. My last question is which authentication flow we need to use to have a GApps Login, either to user OAuth 2.0 or OpenID 2.0. As till now We were using OpenID 1.0.